# Time Discrepancy after Exporting Report in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, export-to-excel

We are facing an issue in 'Export to Excel' function in Report Wizard. We have created one simple report using OOB Report Wizard(not SSRS), which contains few DateTime fields like CreatedOn. The DateTime values showing in CRM & Report Viewer is with respect to logged-in user's timezone(UTC+8) as expected. But after exporting report to excel, it is showing the time with 8 Hrs delay(UTC). We are expecting these DateTime values to be same as in CRM even after exporting it to excel.

Is this a bug from CRM? Can anyone help to fix this issue, please?

Thanks,

Data Mismatch Screenshot:
[image]

Report XML:

```
     <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_FullName">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_FullName</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>administrator</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_UserTimeZoneName">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value></Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_UserTimeZoneName</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_UILanguageId">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>18441</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_UILanguageId</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_CurrencyDecimalPrecision">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>2</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_CurrencyDecimalPrecision</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_CurrencySymbol">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>$</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_CurrencySymbol</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_CurrencyPositivePattern">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_CurrencyPositivePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_CurrencyNegativePattern">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_CurrencyNegativePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_NumberDecimalDigits">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>2</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_NumberDecimalDigits</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_NumberDecimalSeparator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>.</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_NumberDecimalSeparator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_NumberNegativePattern">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_NumberNegativePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_NumberGroupSizes">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>3</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_NumberGroupSizes</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_NumberGroupSeparator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>,</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_NumberGroupSeparator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_CalendarTypeCode">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_CalendarTypeCode</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_DateSeparator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>/</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_DateSeparator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_TimeSeparator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>:</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_TimeSeparator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_AMDesignator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>AM</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_AMDesignator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_PMDesignator">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>PM</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_PMDesignator</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_ShortDatePattern">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>d/M/yyyy</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_ShortDatePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_LongDatePattern">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>dddd, d MMMM, yyyy</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_LongDatePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_ShortTimePattern">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>h:mm tt</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_ShortTimePattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_MonthDayPattern">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>dd MMMM</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_MonthDayPattern</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_YearStartWeekCode">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_YearStartWeekCode</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_WeekStartDayCode">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_WeekStartDayCode</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_FilterText">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_FilterText</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_FilteredIncident">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>&lt;fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"&gt;&lt;entity name="incident"&gt;&lt;all-attributes /&gt;&lt;filter type="and"&gt;&lt;condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="60" /&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/entity&gt;&lt;/fetch&gt;</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>CRM_FilteredIncident</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_URL">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_URL</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="CRM">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>MSCRMFETCH</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>http://serverName:5555/;orgName</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DSMain">
      <Query>
        <CommandText>&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical"&gt;&lt;entity name="incident" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredIncident"&gt;&lt;attribute name="title" alias="title" /&gt;&lt;attribute name="createdon" alias="createdon" /&gt;&lt;attribute name="new_datereceived" alias="new_datereceived" /&gt;&lt;attribute name="new_dateclosed" alias="new_dateclosed" /&gt;&lt;attribute name="incidentid" /&gt;&lt;/entity&gt;&lt;/fetch&gt;</CommandText>
        <DataSourceName>CRM</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="CRM_FilteredIncident">
            <Value>=Parameters!CRM_FilteredIncident.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="title">
          <DataField>title</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="createdon">
          <DataField>createdon</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="createdonValue">
          <DataField>createdonValue</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="new_datereceived">
          <DataField>new_datereceived</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="new_datereceivedValue">
          <DataField>new_datereceivedValue</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="new_dateclosed">
          <DataField>new_dateclosed</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="new_dateclosedValue">
          <DataField>new_dateclosedValue</DataField>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="incidentid">
          <DataField>incidentid</DataField>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <CodeModules>
    <CodeModule>Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</CodeModule>
  </CodeModules>
  <CustomProperties>
    <CustomProperty>
      <Name>Custom</Name>
      <Value>&lt;MSCRM xmlns="mscrm"&gt;&amp;lt;ReportFilter&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ReportEntity paramname="CRM_FilteredIncident" donotconvert="1"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;entity name="incident"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;all-attributes /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;filter type="and"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="60" /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/filter&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/entity&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/fetch&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/ReportEntity&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/ReportFilter&amp;gt;&lt;/MSCRM&gt;</Value>
    </CustomProperty>
  </CustomProperties>
```

Comment: Maybe your report has Excel-specific logic in it? Test with a brand new report that outputs just the DateTime value and see what happens. It should be in the timezone of the executing user if the value is selected from the Filtered View.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a very simple report by adding only a CreatedOn field. It is working fine with UR8, but not in UR18. My reports doesn't contain any excel specific logic. This is a simple report built using OOB report wizard.

Comment: Can you post the simplified report file here?

Comment: I saw the same behavior before and don't suspect this to be a bug, these datetime values are stored UTC and thus exported as such. Are you selecting straight from MSCRM tables or are you using `filtered` views? (CLUE: your answer lies in this)

Comment: Added my report XML code.
This report doesn't contains any SQL query. Its a plain and simple report created using report wizard.

Answer (score 0):

CRM displays the time converted from UTC to whatever time zone is listed in your personal options.  Excel has no concept of what your time zone is, so it takes whatever is listed in the db without converting it.

What's odd is that when you do the same thing through advanced find and export to excel, it does keep the time zones aligned (it exports in whatever time zone you are listed in).  I think the bug is that there is inconsistency between exporting to excel from reports vs views (either behavior on its own could be argued to be correct).

Just FYI, Shane_Yo is right, this report is hitting the FilteredIncident view in the sql db as indicated in the "Custom Properties" Value node at the end of the report xml.